# Share redis with python and java application

Tags: java, python, redis

I'd like to share a redis database with python and java application.
What I'm trying to do is

- Update redis database using python.
- Use the updated values in java application.

However, when I save a string or a list object in python, they are saved as bytes. So when I tried to load the values in java, it says `cannot deserialize`.

How can I solve it? I even don't know if it's possible or not...

I want something like

- python

  `strict_redis_object.set("key", list_which_java_can_understand)`
  or if it's not possible,
  `strict_redis_object.set("key", string_which_java_can_understand)`
- java
  `SomeType value = valueOperationsObject.get("key")`

Comment: If you're interested in a list, use Redis' LPUSH from Python and LRANGE from Java

Comment: Wow thanks. So simple :) I'm not familiar with redis and what a silly question...